# The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required in GetResponse(); C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make a Log in request in my app by method "POST" . I made some progress except >>

```
 loginRes = (HttpWebResponse)loginReq.GetResponse();
```

Searched for hours actually, the whole night yesterday,
I have tried setting this, and tried many numbers too

```
loginRes.ContentLength = 0; // but I know it isn't 0.
```

I can actually know how to get the content length, a quick code snippet >>

```
loginReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(LinkURL);
        loginReq.Method = "POST";
        loginRes = (HttpWebResponse)loginReq.GetResponse(); //error 411 here
        loginRes.ContentLength = 0; 
        loginReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        loginReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
        loginReq.Referer = LinkURL.ToString();
        loginReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        loginReq.KeepAlive = true;
        loginReq.CookieContainer = loginCookie;
```

I know that 0 is wrong, but just to prevent errors in code not compilation, I put it. 
I put `ContentLength = 0;` in "GET" requests, First time trying to make a "POST" request.

Comment: The server isn't returning any data so that is the root cause of the error message.  Best way of debugging issue is using fiddler.  I usually capture fiddler results from manually going to web page with an IE.  Then compare fiddler results with application that is failing.  Usually the issue is the http headers.  To solve issue usually requires adding missing headers to application.  Most common cause is HttpRequest defaulting to http 1.1.  So I simply add : loginReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: I'll try this asap